# Why npm module mysql does not work when you attempt call function 'connect()' in other file's .js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm

I am call require('mysql') and if call function connect() to everything works, but if call function 'connect()' in other file to throw error `connection.connect is not a function`...
how to solve this problem without plugging in another file module?

Answer (score 0):

In node you can't `require` a module in one file and then have it be globally available in another. This is because node implements the [`Module Wrapper`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper).

If you want to use a module in multiple files then one way, and probably the most common, to do that would be to `require()` that module in every file that depends upon it. Node is also efficient about this by making all modules singletons so only a single instance of that loaded module exists for any one `node` process, this is called [Module Caching](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_caching).

Alternatively, instead of using `require()` in every module that needs the given package, you could use [Dependency Injection](https://blog.risingstack.com/dependency-injection-in-node-js/) to pass along the instance of the module.

There is no right or wrong between the two approaches, its all about what fits the scenario.